# Lost Access to files and bucket switching from Fine Grain ACL to Uniform

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gcloud, uniform

I'm testing GC-COLDLINE for the first time. I'm very new to this.

How do I regain access to my bucket and it's contents after changing permissions for Fine Grain to Uniform? I think from what I've read that I prefer the Uniform approach. At the moment I'm unable to make any changes and I'm not able to see the contents of the bucket. I'm unable to delete the bucket.

I am the owner of this account and the owner of the bucket or I was until the above change.

To make sure that I've not pouched the whole account I made another bucket with the Uniform permissions and add a file. Everything within bucket is working perfectly.

If necessary I've got access to the GC-Dashboard or I've got access to Gcloud on my Linux box.